# in local HTML JS file is not working WKWeb swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

[simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur7UY.png)

[Browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nc5C.jpg)

//Simple HTML file: test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Welcome to JavaScript</p>
<form>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="msg()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

//simple JS file: lib.js

```
function msg(){
 alert("Hello Javatpoint");
}
```

// WebViewController

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import SVProgressHUD

class GDCommonWebVC: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak private var webContainerView: UIView!
    private var webView: WKWebView!

    //MARK:- View Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Setup WebView
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    
        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webConfiguration.preferences = preferences
    
        let frame = webContainerView.bounds
        webView = WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webContainerView.addSubview(webView)
    
        let localFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "html")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: localFilePath!)
        webView.load(request as URLRequest)
     }

     override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
     }
   }
    extension GDCommonWebVC: WKNavigationDelegate {
       func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation   navigation: WKNavigation!) {
          SVProgressHUD.show()
       }
       
       func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
          DLog("Failed to load!! = \(error.localizedDescription)")
    
          SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
       }

       func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
          DLog("Failed during navigation: \(error.localizedDescription)")
          SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
          handleError(error)
       }
       func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
          SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
       }

       private func handleError(_ error: Error) {
          let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error!!!", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)       
          let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .destructive) 
          { [weak self](action) in                
              self?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
           }
           alertController.addAction(okAction)
           self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
     }
```

// added this code in .info plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true />
 </dict>
```

Using above code, HTML is loading perfectly but tap on button js function is not triggering.

Note: if I trigger message() function from swift code, it's working but I want to trigger that function call from HTML as like web. I search about this but do not found any solution. If iOS do not support JS then please share any references regarding this.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can try using the "runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage" method to handle the alerts coming from the WKWebView

Comment: actually its not about only alert handling. above code is just an example. I want to load js in webview but without want to trigger js function from webview. want to trigger js function from html. as this HTML file works fine in safari or chrome browser